# PHP Subir un nivel en una ruta para eliminar una imagen ../

Tags: php, imagen

Tengo un formulario donde puedes subir y eliminar imagenes que se guardan en una carpeta que está a un nivel superior. Esta es la ruta:

- Imagenes_folder/imagen.jpg
- Form_folder/form.html

Desde form.html quiero eliminar una imagen pero no encuentra la ruta en php. `$_POST['archivo']` contiene el nombre de la imagen, en este ejemplo seria "imagen.jpg"

```
<?php
$mainRoot = "..//" . "Imagenes_folder//";
if (isset($_POST['archivo'])) {  
    $archivo = $_POST['archivo'];
    $ruta = $mainRoot . basename($archivo);
    if (file_exists($ruta)) {
        unlink($ruta);
    }
}
?>
```

No me reconoce la ruta. Si cambio form.html para que esté en el mismo nivel que Imagenes_folder si me funciona:

- Imagenes_folder/imagen.jpg
- form.html

  ```
      $mainRoot = "Imagenes_folder//";
      if (isset($_POST['archivo'])) {  
          $archivo = $_POST['archivo'];
        $ruta = $mainRoot . basename($archivo);
           if (file_exists($ruta)) {
              unlink($ruta);
          }
      }
  ```

"..//" Esta no es la forma de subir un nivel? He probado con "../" y "../../"

Comment: Una pregunta. Por qué concatenas la ruta? No puedes poner la ruta entera? `$mainRoot = "../Imagenes_folder//";`

Comment: Es raro, según tu estructura debería de funcionar "../Imagenes_folder/" aunque veo que al final estas colocando dos // quita uno y deja solo uno como en el ejemplo que te acabo de colocar

Comment: En la pregunta no dices cómo están los directorios, o sea, a cuántos niveles está `Form_folder` de `Imagenes_folder`... si están ambos al mismo nivel en el root, etc.

Comment: Añade una línea de depuración al final del bloque `if (file_exists($ruta)) {`, por ejemplo `die("entra por if");` así podrás ver si se está ejecutando la instrucción en su interior, es posible que tu ruta no exista y no encuentre el fichero.

Comment: No puedo poner la ruta porque el nombre de la carpeta Imagenes la cojo de la base de datos dependiendo del usuario logado. He puesto Imagenes_folder como ejemplo pero hay varias carpetas que contienen imagenes por usuario. La carpeta Imagenes_folder y la carpeta form_folder estan al mismo nivel. Lo que me resulta extraño es que si elimino la carpeta form_folder y el archivo form.html queda en el mismo nivel que Imagenes_folder sí me funciona, es decir, si no pongo en la ruta "../" antes del nombre de la carpeta de Imagenes. Por eso pensaba que no era la forma correcta de subir un nivel en php.

Comment: Si ambas carpetas están al mismo nivel no tienes que poner nada delante, solamente el nombre del achivo: `imagen.png`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas. Finalmente lo que me ha funcionado para subir un nivel es "./" (solamente un punto)

He encontrado la solución aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169286/file-exists-isnt-finding-the-file

Comment: ¿Esto no te funcionó: `$ruta=dirname(__FILE__, 2);`?

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de hacer lo que quieres sería con [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.dirname.php) el cual:

> Devuelve la ruta de un directorio padre
>
> Dada una cadena que contiene la ruta a un fichero o directorio, esta
>   función devolverá la ruta del directorio padre que está a `levels`
>   niveles del directorio actual.

`levels`

> El número de directorios padre a subir.
>
> Debe ser un número entero mayor que 0.

Si usas PHP 7 este código te daría la ruta de un directorio hacia atrás del directorio donde corre el script: `dirname(__FILE__, 2)`

Si cambias el número dos por un `3` retrocedería otro directorio más hacia la raíz y así sucesivamente.

Para PHP 5 o inferior, sería lo mismo, sólo que no admite números y tendrías que expresar el retroceso de directorios usando `dirname` y paréntesis por cada retroceso.

```
<?php

#PHP 7  
#Un directorio hacia atrás  
$ruta=dirname(__FILE__, 2);
echo $ruta; 
echo "<hr />";


#Dos directorios hacia atrás    
$ruta=dirname(__FILE__, 3);
echo $ruta; 
echo "<hr />";


#PHP 5

#Un directorio hacia atrás  
$ruta_php5=dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
echo $ruta_php5;
echo "<hr />";


#Dos directorios hacia atrás    
$ruta_php5=dirname(
                    dirname(
                                dirname(__FILE__)
                            )
            );

echo $ruta_php5;
?>
```

### Resultado:

Suponiendo que el script está en un directorio dentro de `test`:

Nótese que no agrega el `/` al final, por lo que habría que concaternarlo al nombre del archivo para que la ruta no falle: `/archivo.txt`.

PHP 7

```
/home/miusuario/public_html/test
/home/miusuario/public_html
```

PHP 5

```
/home/miusuario/public_html/test
/home/miusuario/public_html
```